# How to convert char array to int?

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char str[10];
  int x, y, z;
  for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++){
    str[i] = i;
  }

  sscanf(str, "%d", &x); // Using sscanf
  printf("\nThe value of x : %d", x);

  y = atoi(str); // Using atoi()
  printf("\nThe value of y : %d", y);

  return 0;
}
```

I tried using both `sscanf` and `atoi`, but neither of them seems to work. Any idea how to convert `str` to an `int`?

Comment: You need to provide a string you want to convert!  Try `char str[10] = "12345";`, and get rid of the `for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++) { str[i] = i; }` loop.

Comment: You can't use `strlen` on an uninitialized array. Use `sizeof str`. (Also do `i = 0` and `i < sizeof str` so you don't write past the end, and then make sure to put NUL `\0` at the end). Oh and do `str[i] = i + '0';`

Comment: Dude - `sscanf(str, "%d", &x);` and `y = atoi(str);` with both read "int" values into x and y respectively ... provided "str" has a valid string of numeric digits in the first place!  Your "for()" loop has multiple problems: 1) you can't call strlen() until the string has actually been initialized. 2) You can't hope to treat a binary digit "1" (binary 0x1) the same as an ASCII digit "1" (binary 0x31)!  3) you never bothered to null-terminate string "str".

Comment: Rolled back edits so as to not invalidate answers.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++){
    str[i] = i;
}
```

is strange and wrong.  If you were trying to use that loop to construct the string to convert, try this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    str[i] = (i + 1) + '0';
}
str[i] = '\0';

printf("The string: %s\n", str);
```

Here I've made several changes:

1. The loop runs from 0 to 4, to set just the first 5 positions in `str[]`.  (Your loop started at 1, which meant it failed to set `str[0]`, and it tried to run until `strlen(str)`, which can't work because `str` hasn't been set to anything, so you can't compute its length.)
2. When storing values into `str[i]`, it adds 1 to `i` (meaning it will set positions `[0]` to `[4]`), and then additionally adds in the constant `'0'` (which is 48 on an ASCII machine) to convert the numbers 1 — 5 to the digit characters `'1'` to `'5'`.
3. After setting 5 digits, it sets `str[i] = '\0';` to add proper null termination for the constructed string.

Then it prints out `str` so you can see what it is, before trying to convert it to an `int` using `atoi` and `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char myarray[] = "-123";
int i;
sscanf(myarray, "%d", &i);
```

will convert char array to int

Comment: `char myarray[] = "-123";` is sufficient and much less typing, though what you have is correct.